# Auto Suggest search implementation

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I am working on a content oriented website, I have to implement web search, I am thinking of auto suggest search, like this:
 [image]

How it can be done?
I want suggestions followed by the search term as in image, I am using lamp stack.

Suggest me some methods to implement this.

Comment: Just search about AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Write PHP code that will take search keywords and return results in JSON format
2. Create form in HTML
3. On every key stroke in search box take search keywords and make AJAX request to search code you made in step 1
4. Now display the search response you received in JOSN format

http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-autocomplete-using-php-mysql-and-jquery

Comment: i also have categories like shown in image,i want that suggestion should also point to what category to shoose,see image properly

Comment: While returning search result in JSON, return result with category. Then display results in category wise using JS + CSS.

Comment: can you explain it using example please

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in your website, you need to know about AJAX and Database in PHP or any other Server Side language. Then you can use Full Text Search in SQL to do the query. So:

1. PHP mysqli
2. AJAX
3. Full Text Search (Match & Against)

Comment: i also have categories like shown in image,i want that suggestion should also point to what category to show,see image properly plz

Comment: There is two categories. Products and suggested. When you do a full text search query. It will return results sorted by the most similarity and relevance to the search query. Something like google. So you can show the exact results in the first and the other in the suggested. If there are products with same name in multiple categories. The query is same as before. You need to order them by their group and proccess that in your php file.